# Why isn't this working? (C# Place And Destroy script.)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to fix this for hours. It says "Clone" does not exist in the current context. And also it says that The left-hand of an assignment must be a variable, a property, or an indexer. Any tips?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class ClickAndDestroy : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                BoxCollider bc = hit.collider as BoxCollider;
                if (bc != null)
                {
                    Destroy(bc.gameObject);
                }
                else if (bc != null)
                {
                    null = true;
                    Clone(bc.gameObject);
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `null = true;` supposed to do?! And well there is no method called `Clone` within your class or `MonoBehaviour` so where do you think it should come from? You probably want to use `Instantiate` instead which can also be used to clone existing objects in the scene. Also both your cases `if(bc != null) { ...} else if(bc != null) { ... }` are exactly equal => the second case will never be executed .. it might even throw at least a warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main error is 'The left-hand of an assignment must be a variable, a property, or an indexer'. This is occurring with `null = true` as null is not a variable, property or indexer and therefore cannot be assigned `true`. I am unsure what your intentions with this line are, but you will have to remove this line or replace it with other code that does what you need.

This error is probably leaving other unrelated errors in the next lines of code, which is the `Clone(bc.gameObject)` line.

Answer (score 1):

`null = true;` typically you write true/false into a boolean. null is not a boolean. It's nothing. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/null

Also I'm not aware of any funtion in unitys namespace called `Clone`. Can you link a documentation? Have you tried using `Instatiate` instead?
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Good luck